# Check if dates are consecutive

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with check-up dates as the index and a category and type of species.

```
Date    Category    Type
2016-11-21  Cat Animal
2016-11-21  Cat Animal
2017-01-03  Cat Animal
2016-11-01  Dog Animal
2017-01-03  Dog Animal
2016-10-03  Dog Animal
2017-02-01  Dog Animal
2017-03-01  Dog Animal
2016-12-01  Dog Animal
2016-11-21  Horse   Animal
2016-12-15  Horse   Animal
2017-02-04  Horse   Animal
```

I need to determine for each category whether the dates were consecutive . Consecutive could mean a month is missing, this is seen in the horse category. The month of January is missing for horse, but overall the horse's check-up updates are increasing. So horse is valid. 
Cat, however, is invalid since it received a check up twice in one day.

The final dataframe should be

```
Date    Category    Type
2016-11-01  Dog Animal
2017-01-03  Dog Animal
2016-10-03  Dog Animal
2017-02-01  Dog Animal
2017-03-01  Dog Animal
2016-12-01  Dog Animal
2016-11-21  Horse   Animal
2016-12-15  Horse   Animal
2017-02-04  Horse   Animal
```

Comment: If `2016-11-21` is chaged to `2016-12-17` then `Horse` is invalid ?

Comment: Do you care about the order in which Dates appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`is_unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.is_unique.html) and [`is_monotonic_increasing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.is_monotonic_increasing.html) with [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
df = df.groupby('Category').filter(lambda x: x.index.is_unique and 
                                             x.index.is_monotonic_increasing)
print (df)
           Category    Type
Date                       
2016-11-21    Horse  Animal
2016-12-15    Horse  Animal
2017-02-04    Horse  Animal
```

Comment: But Dog should also be valid

Comment: Then use `df.groupby('Category').filter(lambda x: x.index.is_unique)` - another answer.

Comment: Or maybe is necessary better explain if `consecutive == not unique index values  per group` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can exclude animals for which the index is not unique:

```
df.groupby('Category').filter(lambda x: x.index.is_unique)
```

which gives the desired output:

```
           Category    Type
Date                       
2016-11-01      Dog  Animal
2017-01-03      Dog  Animal
2016-10-03      Dog  Animal
2017-02-01      Dog  Animal
2017-03-01      Dog  Animal
2016-12-01      Dog  Animal
2016-11-21    Horse  Animal
2016-12-15    Horse  Animal
2017-02-04    Horse  Animal
```

Your question would suggest you want the dates to be strictly increasing, then you can do:

```
def index_diff(x):
    return ((d_1 - d_0).days for d_1, d_0 in zip(x.index[1:], x.index[:-1]))

df.groupby('Category').filter(lambda x: min(index_diff(x))> 0)
```

Although this only returns

```
           Category    Type
Date                       
2016-11-21    Horse  Animal
2016-12-15    Horse  Animal
2017-02-04    Horse  Animal
```

since for Dog you have `2017-01-03` appearing before `2016-10-03`